# Get Image matrix from histogram matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matrix, histogram

I want to change the values in histogram matrix of an image and then want to have the new image with changed histogram, so I have changed the values in histogram matrix but I am not able to show the image in matlab, can anyone help me by telling how to have the new image?

Comment: Have you checked the `histeq` function?

Comment: yea but I want the histogram values to be constant in the interval of 32 values, histeq doesn't do that

Comment: @Anmol: I don't understand your issue, what is wrong with histeq

Comment: @Daniel: yes, I have used it in my program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the histogram itself doesn't affect the image matrix from which you calculated it directly.

However, as Luis has suggested in the comments, you can use `histeq`. You need to give it an additional input - the histogram you want the output image to match (here, `I` is your original image, and `hgram` is your modified histogram matrix):

```
J = histeq(I,hgram);
```